# "Close of losing" or "Close to losing" or something else?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say something like:

> No one else could be this close of losing the race.

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: we are **close to** VERB-ing not "close *of* " VERB-ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Close to losing" is correct and is commonly used.

Comment: Please edit to include an explanation of why this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: @P.E.Dant And I normally try to include such explanations. But in this case I'm hard pressed to say what the general rule is, so I tried to sneak through with a short answer.

Comment: You might note that _close,_ when talking about proximity, takes a number of preps, e.g. _to, on, upon, about, beside, behind, below, in,_ but never _of._

Comment: @P.E.Dant Hey, if you can give a better answer, feel free. I readily admit this is not one of my best answers.

Comment: Not me! I'm lazier than you are.

Comment: I'm not lazy! I'm ignorant! Oh, wait, I'm not sure that that's better ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct form would be: "No one else could be this close to the loss of the race".

Comment: Your sentence is correct, but "No one else could be this close to losing the race" is also correct.